# Is the gerund correct with "whether"?

Tags: grammar, gerunds

> After pressing it shows a message box asking whether the user wants to take a picture with the device, or better attaching a picture from the device's gallery.

I am not sure about the gerund or what structure should be going with it because it depends on the "whether" in the above line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a *dangling* construction, so called because your reader is expecting that the subject of the main clause will be associated with the active-voice gerund.  That is, whoever is doing the pressing is expected to be the same as whoever is doing the showing.  But that's not what your sentence says.  Presumably the user is doing the pressing, and the button is doing the showing.  The simplest fix is to substitute the passive-voice gerund, *being*+past participle:

> After being pressed, it shows a message box.

Now the thing being pressed is the same as the thing showing a message box.

This also solves another unfortunate characteristic of your original -- a *garden path*, which is phrasing that misleads your reader into taking an incorrect parse.  Your reader may think

> After pressing it, ...

understanding *it* to be the object of the *pressing* instead of the subject with *shows*.

While you're at it, you may as well solve your parallel problem. Either you mean

> [1] it shows a message box or it attaches a picture

or

> [2] to take a picture or to attach a picture

If [1], you need to have two finite verbs (*shows*, *attaches*). If [2], you need to have two infinitives (*to take*, *to attach*).  You've got two different verb forms.